# How can one detect DocumentWindow movement and/or resizing?

Tags: dm-script

Past questions have dealt with detection of changes within the DigitalMicrograph UI such as closing of image windows or changes to ROIs, for which there is a good set of listener events available.  Are there similar ways to detect the movement or resizing of DocumentWindow objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such messages exist for the documentWindow listener.

Similar to the *window_closed* message you can also use *window_begin_drag*, *window_end_drag*, *window_move_or_size*, *window_updated* and *window_opened* messages.

However, **these event messages have been added since GMS 3.0 only**.